# avplayer fullscreen

Tags: fullscreen, avplayer, avasset

I have a AVPlayer used with an AVAsset for playing a video.

I added some controls like play, stop, forward etc...

But how can I switch to fullscreen with a button? I don't want to use MPMoviePlayerController because I don't know how to synchronize starttime. But how can I simply "expand" current playerView to use fullScreen?

Thanks.

Comment: have you been able to solve this? the answers below do not work if the current view is not already fullscreen

Answer (score 3):

1. If AvPlayer has same frame as view or window

   - To make AVPlayer as full screen you have to give total frame of window to AVPlayer layer than rotate a view by pi/2 .
2. If AvPlayer has  less frame of view or window

   - Create on protocal to parent to change frame of player to window frame when user presses landscape button
   - Rotate a view by pi/2.

create one method and use below code.

```
-(void)enlarge
{
    if(!_isLandscapeMode)
    {
        [self.landscapeDelegate changeFrameForLandscapeMode:YES];
        [_landscapeMode setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:IMAGE_NAME_PORTRAIT_MODE] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        _isLandscapeMode=YES;

        self.transform =  CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
    }
    else
    {
        [self.landscapeDelegate changeFrameForLandscapeMode:NO];
        _isLandscapeMode=NO;
        [_landscapeMode setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:IMAGE_NAME_LANDSCAPE_MODE] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.transform =  CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Lets say you have a `UIViewController` that has a UIView fullscreen

You need to use AVPlayerLayer

```
var player = AVPlayer(playerItem: AVPlayerItem(asset: asset))
var layer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
self.view.layer.addSublayer(layer)
layer.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I added the following lines in my code,

```
 [playerLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
```

It will show full screen now.